# Dynamically insert data in a table name

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a grade system, and I need some help.

I am creating a registration form, I've managed to insert the user details in the 'users' table, but I also want to insert the user ID and username in to a group table.

For example:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `password`, `email`, `group`, `ip`, `signup`, `lastlogin`) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password','$group','$ip',now(),now())");
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
        // Establish their row in the group table
        $sql = ("INSERT INTO '.$group.'(id, username) VALUES ('$uid','$username')");
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

        exit();
```

I'm not sure how I can put a dynamic variable ($group) as the table name and then insert the data in the correct group tables.

If anyone has a suggestion or now how to achieve this, any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Psssst... mysqli is a good step but you must use prepared statements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629328/how-to-use-mysqli-prepared-statements-in-php

Comment: I think you should create `group` table first and then try to insert data into that table.

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau Thanks a lot! I will use prepared statements now on! For anyone who would like it a good video is http://youtu.be/jSo0UDlATbw that help me understand.

Comment: No problem, glad to see you're interested to learn! Here's some reading on the "why": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1):

```
"INSERT INTO '.$group.'(id, username) VALUES ('$uid','$username')"
```

You are surrounding $group with the dots and apostrophes - the apostrophes are not splitting the string.

```
"INSERT INTO `$group` (id, username) VALUES ('$uid','$username')"
```

- notice the back-ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
"INSERT INTO '$table' (username,password) VALUES ('$username','$password')"
```

I'd recommend you to use prepared statements instead, though.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Those should be back-ticks around $table. I'm also assuming that $group is the name of a table.

Comment: In fact there's absolutely no need to add ticks, at all. I just used them to organize the code a little bit better so it's easy to understand. And indeed, in his case $table would be $group, but once again this was a simple example for reference only.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. My problem was that i had $group = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']); but I needed $group = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#', '', $_POST['g']); it now works as intented. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First create table with your desired name

```
$sql = ("CREATE TABLE `".$group."` (id,username);");
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

$sql = ("INSERT INTO `".$group."` (id, username) VALUES ('".$uid."','".$username."')");
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

This works.

mysql_query("INSERT INTO '.$group.'(id, username) VALUES ('$uid','$username')");