# Php with id that has underscore and numbers

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem with my code. It works fine when i use id for example 1000000 but when i use id 1000000_1 it returns me error not when i m trying to insert it into mysql but when i call it to edit the record. 
id_fakelos=5979&CD_CAND=2015020010_1&kod_prok=2834

The error is "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in" and my code to call it is

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM fakelos WHERE CD_CAND = {$CD_CAND} LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
extract($row);
```

The code works perfectly when i m not using underscores

Comment: This is not related to your question, but I strongly advice you to start using PDO library instead of mysqli functions: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: Since 1000000_1 is not numeric, you should add quotes around the value `SELECT * FROM fakelos WHERE CD_CAND = '{$CD_CAND}' LIMIT 1`

Comment: »Returns FALSE on failure.« Read the documentation! http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Besides, you should show how you store 1000000_1 as a variable, and what's the datatype of fakelos ? int? varchar2?

Comment: @Giorgio: That's bull. `mysqli` (not `mysql`) is a perfectly good choice.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you do `...&CD_CAND=1 AND (SELECT SUBSTR(password,1,1) FROM users WHERE name='Admin')='a'&...` This injection should allow me to find out individual characters of your password. Judging by the fantastic quality of the code in your question, I would be fairly safe in assuming you either save passwords in plain text, or with something broken like unsalted MD5.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because `1000000_1` is not a valid literal outside quotes in MySql.

Putting quotes around it would fix the immediate issue, but there is a much bigger problem with your code: **you are not using prepared statements with bound parameters**.

Changing the code to [use prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9629328/50079) will make it robust in the face of [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/50079) and will fix your problem "for free".