# MySQL add values to SET element

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a new row to my database with the help of a php form.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
first_name      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
last_name       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
languages       SET('english', 'greek', 'german', 'japanese', 'spanish', 'italian', 'french', 'wookie', 'klingon', 'other') NOT NULL,
pid             INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(pid)
);
```

First, I have the above MySQL table.

Then, with the following code, I get the field values for everything

```
<form class="sform" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="" placeholder="First name" maxlength="30">
<input type="text" name="last_name" value="" placeholder="Last name" maxlength="30">
<select multiple="multiple" id="languages" name="languages[]">
                <option value='english'>English</option>
                <option value='greek'>Greek</option>
                <option value='german'>German</option>
                <option value='japanese'>Japanese</option>
                <option value='spanish'>Spanish</option>
                <option value='italian'>Italian</option>
                <option value='french'>French</option>
                <option value='wookie'>Wookie</option>
                <option value='klingon'>Klingon</option>
                <option value='other'>Other</option>
            </select>
</form>
```

**Note at this point** that this is a multiple select form.(a person may speak more than 1 language)

Then, using `php` I get the values for each element of the table, but for the one i'm most interested in I do the following:

```
$qfirst_name     = $_POST['first_name'];
$qlast_name      = $_POST['last_name'];
$qlanguages      = "'" . implode("','", $_POST['languages']) . "'";
```

The reason I call the `implode` method here is that so I get a string back in the following form: `ex.'english','greek'` But, that is not how MySQL accepts SETs to be initialized so, I replace the `single quotes` like so:

```
$qlanguages = str_replace('\'', '', $qlanguages);
```

Now, $qlanguages would be: `ex.english,greek`
But that's still not close enough, so the final step is to apply **quotes** in both the beginning and the end of the variable like so: `$qlanguages = '\''.$qlanguages.'\'';`

Finally, $qlanguages is in the correct form `'english,greek'` to be inserted in the database with the following code:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name, languages) 
         VALUES ('$qfirst_name', '$qlast_name', '$qlanguages')";
```

And then I connect to my db in order to add the entry to the database
**Note here** There is another file which establishes the connection and i've just **included** it at the top of my php file.

```
if ($dbconn->query($sql1)) {
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

I've explained my steps as best as I could, and my question is this: Why when I include the `SET` field in my query, I can't insert the new `person` in the database. What am I missing?

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: You're not fixing the security issues with the data, let alone getting your data into the table. You should use a [prepared statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629328/how-to-use-mysqli-prepared-statements-in-php) instead

Comment: Besides it's not very good way of doing db queries to answer your question `$qlanguages` has already `'` around it. You should do `...VALUES ('$qfirst_name', '$qlast_name', $qlanguages)";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did this:

```
$qlanguages = "'english,greek'";
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name, languages) 
     VALUES ('$qfirst_name', '$qlast_name', '$qlanguages')";
```

so you got this:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name, languages) 
     VALUES ('qfirst_name', 'qlast_name', ''english,greek'')";
```

you can see the "double" "single" quotes in place of languages

Comment: You have no idea, how long this has been bugging me... THANKS A LOT GOOD SIR. This is clearly a newbie error, but i'm still an undergrad :)

Answer (score 0):

The `SET` datatype is [stored internally as a binary digit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html). IIRC you can take advantage of that fact and dispense with all this string manipulation. Also, I could erase your database if you put me in front of that web page for 5 seconds. You should use prepared statements to mitigate SQL injection attack risk.

```
<form class="sform" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="" placeholder="First name" maxlength="30">
<input type="text" name="last_name" value="" placeholder="Last name" maxlength="30">
<select multiple="multiple" id="languages" name="languages[]">
                <option value='1'>English</option>
                <option value='2'>Greek</option>
                <option value='4'>German</option>
                <option value='8'>Japanese</option>
                <option value='16'>Spanish</option>
                <option value='32'>Italian</option>
                <option value='64'>French</option>
                <option value='128'>Wookie</option>
                <option value='256'>Klingon</option>
                <option value='512'>Other</option>
            </select>
</form>


<?php
$qfirst_name     = $_POST['first_name'];
$qlast_name      = $_POST['last_name'];
$qlanguages      = array_sum($_POST['languages']);

$stmt = $dbconn->prepare("INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name, languages) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssd", $qfirst_name, $qlast_name, $qlanguages);
if ($stmt->execute($sql1)) {
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
?>
```

Untested, but I did something similar a couple of years ago when I was silly enough to use a `SET` column. Now I would suggest using a separate languages table.

Comment: separate languages tables is 3NF (I think) that's why I think it's better, I was thinking about this couple of hours ago when I couldnt figure out the SET problem at hand.