# Error 'Data truncated for column ...' while calling a MySql stored proc, with SET datatype and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

MySQL table 'item' (simplified):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item;
CREATE TABLE item (
    item_id INTEGER(6) NOT NULL, 
    item_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    item_consumption SET ('racine','fruit','feuille','graine','tubercule','bulbe','fleur','tige'),
    CONSTRAINT pk_item 
            PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
 );
```

MySQL table 'species'

```
CREATE TABLE species (
    spec_id INTEGER(6) NOT NULL,   
    spec_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT pk_species 
        PRIMARY KEY (spec_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_species_item 
        FOREIGN KEY (spec_id) REFERENCES item  (item_id)
);
```

MySQL stored proc 'addSpecies' :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addSpecies;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE addSpecies (
    IN p_item_name VARCHAR(40),
    IN p_item_consumption SET('racine','fruit','feuille','graine','tubercule','bulbe','fleur','tige'),
    IN p_spec_name VARCHAR(40),
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE errno INTEGER;
    DECLARE text VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE item_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    -- GET CURRENT DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 errno = MYSQL_ERRNO;
    -- SELECT errno AS MYSQL_ERROR;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
     @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
    SELECT @full_error;
    ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO item 
        (item_name, item_consumption)
        VALUES
        (p_item_name,p_item_consumption);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO item_id;

    INSERT INTO species (spec_id,spec_name) 
        VALUES (item_id,p_spec_name);

    SELECT item_id;

    COMMIT WORK;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run this stored proc in command mode, it works, but when I call it using PDO, I have got an error :

SQL command :

```
CALL addSpecies(:item_name,:item_consumption,:spec_name)
```

Bind array :

```
Array ( [:item_name] => test  [:item_consumption] => racine,feuille,tubercule,fleur  [:spec_name] => test)
```

error message :

```
erreur SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'p_item_consumption' at row 1
```

I tried using VARCHAR(100) for parameter, but the message is now for the database column.

Thanks for help

### **EDIT 1**

PDO does support only numeric and string parameter binds.

Data type SET is MySQL specific.

Options :

1. use a mixed PDO parameter binds for numeric and string parameters, and value for the set type. ( [MySQL add values to SET element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912084/mysql-add-values-to-set-element) )
2. convert SET datatype to VARCHAR(255) (or less)
3. use 2 tables to manage the n-n relationship between 'item' and 'consumption'

@Strawberry comment '...abomination...' : SET datatype converts this set to an integer. If you change the order of items in the fields description, your data becomes incoherent ! **I will abandon the datatype SET**

Use a string with values separator need needs code to check values (a trigger could assure that it is ok).

@Shadow comment : '...3NF...' : 'consumption' and 'consumptionItem' : each update needs DELETE consumptionItem for the item, and INSERT new consumptionItem

These 8 values should never change...but if they change from french to english, for example, nice work to do ! I will test the last 2 solutions and tell which I keep.

### **EDIT 2**

From comments and thoughts, here is the choice I did : thanks for answering !
That works fine !

1) create a new table to store the 8 words (parts of plants that can be eated)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS consumption;
CREATE TABLE consumption (
    cons_name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL COMMENT "Intitulé/Intitulé du mode de consommation",  
    CONSTRAINT pk_consumption
        PRIMARY KEY (cons_name)
)ENGINE = InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8, COMMENT "Modes/Modes de consommation";

INSERT INTO consumption (cons_name)
VALUES 
("racine"),
("fruit"),
("feuille"),
("graine"),
("tubercule"),
("bulbe"),
("fleur"),
("tige");
```

2) create a table to link items to consumptions (for each plant, which part can be eated)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS consumptionveg;
CREATE TABLE consumptionveg (
    veg_id INTEGER(6) NOT NULL, 
    cons_name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_consumptionVeg
            PRIMARY KEY (cons_name, veg_id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_consumptionveg_vegetal 
            FOREIGN KEY (veg_id) REFERENCES vegetal (veg_id)
                ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_consumptionveg_consumption 
            FOREIGN KEY (cons_name) REFERENCES consumption (cons_name)
                ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);
```

3) remove the SET datatype field

4) use a function to split a string : from [Equivalent of explode() to work with strings in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql)

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS split;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION split(
  ch VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(4),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ch, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ch, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

5) create a stored procedure to create 'consumptionveg' from a string (using 'split' function)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS replaceVegConsumption;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE replaceVegConsumption (
    IN p_item_id INTEGER(6),
    IN p_veg_consumption VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE errno INTEGER;
    DECLARE text VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE ct  INT;
    DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE res  VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE sep  VARCHAR(1);

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    SHOW ERRORS;
    ROLLBACK;
    END;
    SET @enabled = TRUE;

  call debug_msg(@enabled, 'avant delete');

    DELETE FROM consumptionveg WHERE veg_id = p_item_id;
  call debug_msg(@enabled, 'apres delete');

    SET ct = 1;
    SET str =  '';
    SET res =  '';
    SET sep =  '';

    loop_label:  LOOP
        IF  ct > 10 THEN 
            LEAVE  loop_label;
        END  IF;
       SET res = trim(split(p_veg_consumption,',',ct));
       if res <> "" then
           if str NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',res,'%') THEN
            SET  str = CONCAT(str,sep,res);
            SET sep = ",";

            INSERT INTO consumptionveg (cons_name, veg_id)
                VALUES (res, p_item_id);

           END IF;
       end if;
        SET  ct = ct + 1;

    END LOOP;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and call it in the main stored proc (simplified) :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addSpecies;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE addSpecies (
... params
    IN p_veg_consumption VARCHAR(255),
... params
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE errno INTEGER;
    DECLARE text VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE item_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;


    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    SHOW ERRORS;
    ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

... insert ......
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO item_id;
... inserts ......


    CALL replaceVegConsumption(item_id, p_veg_consumption);

    SELECT item_id;

    COMMIT WORK;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

6) create a stored function that retreive item consumptions as a string :

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getVegConsumption;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getVegConsumption(
    p_veg_id INT
) RETURNS CHAR(255)  reads sql data
BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        declare i_myfield int;
        declare iter int;
  DECLARE sep CHAR(1);
  DECLARE str CHAR(255);
  DECLARE cursor_VAL CHAR(255);
  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT cons_name 
    FROM consumptionVeg WHERE veg_id = p_veg_id;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
   SET sep = " ";
  SET str = " ";
  SET done = 0;
  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_i INTO cursor_VAL; -- cursor_ID, cursor_VAL;
     IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
     END IF;
     SET str =  CONCAT(trim(str),sep, coalesce(trim(cursor_VAL)," "));
    SET sep = ",";
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
  return str;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

7) use this function to retreive data, convert to checkbox, then to string and submit to stored procedure !

I suppose that my initial problem is due to PDO limitation. (I didn't check for the moment).

Comment: The column is too small for the data you are trying to insert. If you have long strings you can use TEXT as column type to make room.

Comment: But I use SET datatype which is converted into integer value by MySQL engine

Comment: I would normalise your data structure and use separate tables instead of the set data type.

Comment: Yes I know, but it is really a fixed length set of values. If there is no solution, that's what I will do.

Comment: Even if there is a solution, it's still what I'd do. The SET data type is an abomination.

Comment: Incidentally, note that the '6' in 'int(6)' doesn't actually do anything useful

Comment: yes I will remove these values. (I use this 6 value to check integer value up to 999999)