# New row is created with empty values in php using mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using ampps server for my database. Using php I have written script to connect with server database. Now I want to insert data in the database table.

I tried writing the script and new row is getting inserted with null values.

I tried multiple insert queries but did not succeed.

```
  <?php

require("testDB.php");


class insertUserHelper
{

    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $status;


    function insertUserHelper($name,$email,$status)
    {
          $this -> name = $name;
          $this -> email = $email;
          $this -> status = $status;

    }

    function insert()
    {
       $con = testDatabase::getDB();

       echo $name;
       echo $email;
       echo $status;

       $sql =  "INSERT INTO user ". "(name,email,status) ".
       "VALUES ". "('$name','$email','$status')";

       if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                 echo "New record created successfully";
       } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Can anyone help please,very new to php. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating local variables `$name, $email and $status` in your insert() function, try using `$this->name, $this->email and $this->status` instead. And use a prepared statement with bind variables instead of building a vulnerable query like that.

Comment: yes got it. Thank you so much. could you please guide me for the prepared statement for this code. @rypskar

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629328/how-to-use-mysqli-prepared-statements-in-php and the answer here from @NanaPartykar are good places to start using prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO user (name,email,status) VALUES ('$name','$email','$status')";
```

Answer (score 0):

please replace

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO user ". "(name,email,status) ".
       "VALUES ". "('$name','$email','$status')";
```

with

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO user ". "(name,email,status) ".
       "VALUES ". "('$this->name','$this->email','$this->status')";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use **bind_param** to execute your query.
2. Use `$this->name`, `$this->email`, `$this->status` instead of `$name`, `$email`, `$status`.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
function insert()
{
  $con = testDatabase::getDB();

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name,email,status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $this->name, $this->email, $this->status);

  if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
  }
}
```

For More Info, Click [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

**EXPLANATION**

> $stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

The `sss` argument lists the types of data that the parameters are. The `s` character tells mysql that the parameter is a string.

The argument may be one of four types:

1. i - integer
2. d - double
3. s - string
4. b - BLOB

We must have one of these for each parameter. By telling mysql what type of data to expect, we minimize the risk of **SQL injections**.

For more info, click [Prepared Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: What is the second parameter 'sssd' in mysqli_stmt_bind_param? @Nana Partykar