# Get content from Database and Updating the content generates Error

Tags: php, mysqli, joomla

I am retrieving data from the joomla Database.

I am searching for the tag `<img alt=''">` in the content and I want the alt tag value as the articles title.

But when I Update the content in database I get the following **error.**

> "Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 's, each catering to different testing needs of an
>   organization. It has f' at line 1"

Please Check the Code given below.

```
$link= "SELECT * FROM as23dc_content LIMIT 1";
$link_result = mysqli_query($conn, $link);

while($row_link= mysqli_fetch_assoc($link_result)) {

    $content = $row_link["introtext"];

    $add_alt_title = 'alt="'.$row_link["title"].'"';

    $content1 = preg_replace('/(alt)=("[^"]*")/i', "$add_alt_title", $content);

      //echo $content1;

             $sql = "UPDATE as23dc_content SET introtext='".$content1."' WHERE id='".$row_link["id"]."'";
             //print_r($sql);

             if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
}
```

Comment: Just under your `$sql = "UPDATE..."` you have a `print_r($sql)`.  What does it show?

Comment: Are you doing this outside Joomla or inside any joomla extension?

Comment: Tushar It has been a while and you did not select any answer, nor gave any feedback. It takes a lot to understand your problem, find a solution and write it up for you. If a solution worked for you, select and upvote it. If not, at least let us know why so we (who tried to help) can also learn from this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `$content1` string has quotes that confuse the SQL parser because it has a hard time knowing where that value ends.

Use prepared statements instead because they make it impossible for the parser to become confused

```
//Put '?' where the values would be
$sql = "UPDATE as23dc_content SET introtext = ? WHERE id = ?"
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

//bind the values to the '?' parameters (replace 's' with 'i' for integer values)
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $content1, $row_link['id']);

//execute the query and abort on error
$stmt->execute() or die ($stmt->error);

if($stmt->affected_rows) echo "Record updated successfully."
else echo "Record could not be found. No change was made."
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm almost sure that you are generating invalid sql.

```
introtext='".$content1."'
```

witch generate something like
introtext='sometest'
Pay attention to the quotes!
Same goes for

```
id='".$row_link["id"]."'"
```

is the problem (unsafe too)

Please read
[How to use mysqli prepared statements in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629328/how-to-use-mysqli-prepared-statements-in-php)
and official php docs http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score -1):

You can escape single quotes using this

```
$content1 = preg_replace('/(alt)=("[^"]*")/i', "$add_alt_title", $content);
$content1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $content1);//Procedural
```

OR

```
$content1 = preg_replace('/(alt)=("[^"]*")/i', "$add_alt_title", $content);
$content1 = $conn->real_escape_string($content1);//OOPS
```

After this you can insert into database.

Comment: who negatively voted this ans plz give a good reason for that.